# Is there a data structure for effective implementation of this encryption algorithm?

Tags: algorithm, encryption, language-agnostic

input -> alphabet -> output (index of a number in alphabet) -> new alphabet (the number moved to the begin of the alphabet):

3 -> [1, 2, 3, 4, 5] -> 3 -> [3, 1, 2, 4, 5]

2 -> [3, 1, 2, 4, 5] -> 3 -> [2, 3, 1, 4, 5]

1 -> [2, 3, 1, 4, 5] -> 3 -> [1, 2, 3, 4, 5]

1 -> [1, 2, 3, 4, 5] -> 1 -> [1, 2, 3, 4, 5]

4 -> [1, 2, 3, 4, 5] -> 4 -> [4, 1, 2, 3, 5]

5 -> [4, 1, 2, 3, 5] -> 5 -> [5, 4, 1, 2, 3]

input: (n - number of numbers in alphabet, m - length of text to be encrypted, the text)

5, 6

3 2 1 1 4 5

Answer: 3 2 1 1 4 5 -> 3 3 3 1 4 5

Is there any data structure or algorithm to make this efficiently, faster than O(n*m)?

I'd be appreciated for any ideas. Thanks.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Use an [order statistics tree](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Order_statistic_tree) to store the pairs `(1,1)...(n,n)`, ordered by their first elements.

Look up the translation for a character `c` by selecting the `c`-th smallest element of the tree and taking its second element.

Then update the tree by removing the node that you looked up and inserting it back into the tree with the first element of the pair set to `-t`, where `t` is the position in the message (or some other steadily decreasing counter).

Lookup, removal and insertion can be done in `O(ln n)` time worst-case if a self-balanced search tree (e.g. a [red-black tree](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Red%E2%80%93black_tree)) is used as underlying tree structure for the order statistics tree.

Given that the elements for the initial tree are inserted in order, the tree structure can be build in `O(n)`.

So the whole algorithm will be `O(n + m ln n)` time, worst-case.

---

You can further improve this for the case that `n` is larger than `m`, by storing only one node for any continuous range of nodes in the tree, but counting it for the purpose of rank in the order statistics tree according to the number of nodes there *would* normally be.

Starting then from only one actually stored node, when the tree is rearranged, you split the range-representing node into three: one node representing the range before the found value, one representing the range after the found value and one representing the actual value. These three nodes are then inserted back, in case of the range nodes only if they are non-empty and with the first pair element equal to the second and in case of the non-range node, with the negative value as described before. If a node with negative first entry is found, it is not split in this.

The result of this is that the tree will contain at most `O(m)` nodes, so the algorithm has a worst-time complexity of `O(m ln min(n,m))`.

Comment: but if we insert an element back into the tree with the first element of the pair set to -t, how to look up this element next time?

Comment: @OliverWayne You never do a lookup by searching for the first element. Instead your search for rank in the tree. It also doesn't really matter that the value is `-t`. You just need to insert the element before all others in the tree. If you implement this yourself, you can remove the first element completely, since inserts are guaranteed to happen only at the beginning.

Answer (score -1):

Maybe a hashmap with letter/index pairs? I believe that element lookup in a hashmap usually O(1) most of the time, unless you have a lot of collisions (which is unlikely).

Comment: This does not help, because the mapping needs to be modified for each character in the message.